# mssql query takes time finally ends up with socket closed exception

Tags: sql-server-2005, jdbc, connection-pooling

using log4jdbc for logging, log shows following exception :

```
341. {call SOME_PROC('All','31/12/2012','31/12/2012',256,'',0,'All',-1)} 
 {FAILED after 203580 msec}
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: socket closed
```

and then no.of open connections keeps on increasing for each query executed afterwards

```
2012-12-31 16:05:02.713 open connections:  
209 285 287 288 289 290 291 297 302 304 305 306 
307 308 309 312 314 317 330 331 333 336 337 339 
345 346 350 351 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 (37)
```

this continues until tomcat is restarted
why is the socket getting closed?
and what is the solution for this?

Comment: You are most likely not closing connections in your code, or using them in a wrong way. Without some actual code it is impossible to tell.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to optimise your query that takes 200 seconds.

Comment: But why is socket getting closed if query is taking so much time?

Comment: Only sometimes it takes this much time and this is when socket closed occurs..could be a deadlock?

Answer (score 0):

using `BoneCP` solved the issue.